# LaTeX Squeezes Notation in `\frac{}{}` Environment

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I have to write an expression of the form

```latex
\frac{1}{E_{s}^{x}}
```

However, the term is squeezed by TeX in the denominator (the `x` does not have the same height as if I did not use a fraction). Here the output:

[image]

How can the heights be made consistent?

Here is an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
    $$\frac{1}{E_{s}^{x}}$$ $$E_{s}^{x}$$
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If a `\frac` expression is encountered while in `\displaystyle` math mode, the numerator term is typeset in (ordinary) `\textstyle` and the denominator is typeset in so-called "cramped" `\textstyle`. If you don't like this default behavior, you need to insert -- depending on the look you want to achieve -- either `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle` at the start of the denominator material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle E_{s}^{x} \quad 
 \textstyle    E_{s}^{x}$

\bigskip
$\displaystyle 
 \frac{1}{E_{s}^{x}} \quad 
 \frac{1}{\displaystyle E_{s}^{x}} \quad 
 \frac{1}{\textstyle    E_{s}^{x}}$
\end{document}
```